# Alpha reveals some black when scattering with geometry nodes / Overlap

Tags: texturing, geometry-nodes, transparency

Alpha reveals some black while "scattering" with geometry nodes.
Does anyone know why this is happening?
I guess this is a overlap issue.
Because when I play with lower scale and lower density values it doesn't happen.
The shader is placed in a simple squarish subdivided plane.

[image]
[image]